# Test method is always failed if i run it using tesng

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng.xml

Please help me out on this, I am always getting this error tried multiple times

```java
public class BaseClass {
    
    WebDriver driver;
    Properties properties;
    FileInputStream inputstream;
    @BeforeClass
    public void setup() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        FileInputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\admin\\eclipse-workspace\\NiftyUAT1\\src\\test\\java\\com\\pks\\test\\Objects.Properties");
        properties.load(inputstream);
        }

    @Test
    public void test1() { 
        System.out.println(111);
        driver.get(properties.getProperty("URL"));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='login-email']")).sendKeys(properties.getProperty("Email"));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='login-password']")).sendKeys(properties.getProperty("Pwd"));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='login-submit']")).click();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting? Please include all details such as the full stacktrace.

Comment: It's getting failed

Comment: ===============================================
Suite
Total tests run: 1, Passes: 0, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

Comment: It's not executing from this                                          driver.get(properties.getProperty("URL"));
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='login-email']")).sendKeys(properties.getProperty("Email"));
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='login-password']")).sendKeys(properties.getProperty("Pwd"));
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='login-submit']")).click();

Comment: How do you run the test? Are you using an IDE? There should be a tab for failed tests or a detailed console output.

Comment: getting this java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.Properties.getProperty(String)" because "this.properties" is null

Comment: Your InputStream is probably empty then. Verify that the file location is correct first of all, and if it is, then try to log what the value of the inputstream is

Comment: In setup, you declared `properties` as a local variable and never set the field with the same name. Same goes for the other field it seems.

Comment: i change the field name, how to change the local variable what the solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared `driver` and `properties` as local variables, shadowing the field you are using in the test method. Just remove the type in front of the declarations and it should work:

```java
public class BaseClass {
    
    WebDriver driver;
    Properties properties;
    
    @BeforeClass
    public void setup() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        
        properties = new Properties();
        try (FileInputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\admin\\eclipse-workspace\\NiftyUAT1\\src\\test\\java\\com\\pks\\test\\Objects.Properties")) {
            properties.load(inputstream);
        }
    }
    // the rest is the same
}
```

Plus, you probably don't need an `inputstream` field later on so just have the loading use it locally in try-with-resources.

Comment: now getting "Properties can not be resolved to be a variable" on this  properties = new Properties();

Comment: How, what? Please show how you changed your code.